# TFS 2017 Build with Multi-Configuration and Task Group

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2017 build that was setup with multi-Configuration that has a multiplier of BuildConfiguration.  This worked fine with until I took all the build steps and moved them into a Task Group.  Now I get an error that seems to indicate that it's looking at the full string of the variable BuildConfiguration dev,int verses iterating over it. Does this not work with Task Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work.

My problem was the BuildConfiguration variable that gets created in the Task Group has to be set to refer back to the BuildConfiguration variable at the Build level (may be using the wrong term here...).

So instead of setting the Task Group var to dev,int I had to set it to $(BuildConfiguration) which refers it back.

So my task group variables look like this (I highlighted the BuildConfiguration var that was my issue):
[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you got multi-configuration in 2017 tfs?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, Multi-Configuration is not available for Task Group.

When you select all the build steps and create a TaskGroup, you need to set Multi values (eg : `Release,Debug`) for the `buildConfiguration`.

But during the build it will meet this error message :"`Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release,debug|Any CPU" is invalid`"

To correct that error, you need to set it as unique value (eg :`Release` ) or leave it as empty. Thus the build works, but actually it's not the real Multi-Configuration build even though it displays **Release** and **Debug** there. (You can check the build log for the "Multi" builds, you will see the actual msbuild command with argument )

I have submitted a [**feedback here**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/129277/tfs-2017-multi-configuration-build-is-not-availabl.html) for this issue, hope achieve it in future.

[image: image here]

Comment: @Stephen Huff Any update for  the reply? you can track the [feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/129277/tfs-2017-multi-configuration-build-is-not-availabl.html) for further update.

Comment: It's working now but I changed so many things I'm not sure what made it work.  Let me look at it tonight and get back to this post.  Thank you greatly for your time.

Comment: You actually have to set it to refer back to the $(BuildConfiguration) of the build that is using that task group.  I do appreciate you taking the time to look at this though.